# Cases environment compresses fractions?

Tags: cases

what should I do to stop the cases environment compressing the first line of the following?

```
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{mn} = \begin{cases} \frac{16\mu^2}{mn\pi^2\left[\pi^2(m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2) - \mu^2\right]} &\mbox{for } m \mbox{ and } n \mbox{ odd;} 
\\ 0 &\mbox{for } m \mbox{ or } n \mbox{ even;} \end{cases} \\[1ex]
\end{equation}
```

I'm not sure to do tex on this site, but if anyone tries it they see the first case is compressed because it's a fraction.

Comment: Use `\dfrac` for `\displaystyle\frac`

Comment: Yes, `cases` uses `\textstyle`; the package `mathtools` provides `dcases`.

Answer (score 31):

The package `mathtools` (that also loads `amsmath`) provides `dcases` and `dcases*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{mn} =
\begin{dcases*}
\frac{16\mu^2}{mn\pi^2[\pi^2(m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2) - \mu^2]} &
  for $m$ and $n$ odd;\\
0\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}} & for $m$ or $n$ even;
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference between `cases` and `dcases` is that display style is used in the latter, but not in the former. The `dcases*` form sets the second part in text mode, making it more convenient to type textual conditions.

The `\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}` is an adjustment to make the construction more balanced. Note that you don't need `\left` and `\right` in the denominator, which would make the brackets too big.

Answer (score 7):

Two alternatives (I couldn't use the `mathtools` package because it was marked as obsolete) which work in the cases environment:

1. use the function `\mathlarger{}` including the fraction you want to be displayed larger (also works with `\sum` symbol)
2. (only for fractions) use the function `\dfrac{}` instead of `\frac{}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. `mathtools` is not an obsolete package, so I wonder why you'd get that message. And `amsmath` is required for `\dfrac`, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why mathtools is marked as obsolete, the software wouldn't let me install it as other packages. These are my first 72 hours using LaTeX so I can't provide more info.. And to complete the discussion the package relsize is required for \mathlarger{}.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use? It's very odd that you would get a message that the `mathtools` package is obsolete; that's definitely not the case. Incidentally, the `\dfrac` macro was mentioned in a comment below the original posting.

Comment: `mathtools` and friends have recently been ”rearranged“ ... i wonder if that's what is being referenced?  (i catalogued the change on 20 aug)

Comment: my version is TeXstudio 2.8.2

Comment: i like `\dfrac`