# How to insert dcases environment in LyX?

Tags: lyx, cases

I have the same problem as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172693/cases-environment-compresses-fractions). The proposed solution was to use `dcases` or `dcases*` environment. How to do that in LyX? Insert->Math menu has only "Cases Environment".

Comment: I think you have to use ERT

Comment: LyX does not have support for dcases, so you would have to use ERT, or perhaps redefine the cases environment as dcases in the preamble (I have no idea if this would work since I'm not familiar with dcases).

Comment: Hi, Have you found a good solution to this? I can't even figure out how ERT can be used in this context. I know what ERT is, but can't do this for drcases somehow. Fixing preamble is good if that works. But also I can't figure out how to do that